# Jpa query right join on

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with this query in JPA:

```
String query= "SELECT pc.pcKey, c.id, c.pcName 
    FROM Computer c RIGHT JOIN c.pcKey pc ON c.pcKey = pc.pcKey 
    WHERE pc.pcKey IS NOT NULL AND pc.pk.idLaboratory = :laboratoryId";
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
with clause can only reference columns in the driving table [SELECT pc.pcKey, c.id, c.pcName FROM com.want.ecdlejb.hibernate.model.Computer c RIGHT JOIN c.pcKey pc ON c.pcKey = pc.pcKey WHERE pc.pcKey IS NOT NULL AND pc.pk.idLaboratory = :laboratoryId]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker$WithClauseVisitor.visit(HqlSqlWalker.java:508)
```

Entity Computer class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pc_key", nullable=false)
private PcKey pcKey;
```

Entity PcKey Class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pcKey")
private Set<Computer> computerses;
```

I read about some bug with this error, but it was in 2012, i think they fix it already. Anyone know how to make this query correctly?

Comment: "pc.pk.idLaboratory" don't understand.

Comment: Please you write full entity.

Comment: sorry should be pc.idLaboratory

Comment: what table is c.pcKey?  c refers to computer so computer.PCkey is a table?  perhaps you just need to remove c from `c.pckey`  . notation in sql is schema, table, object so is "C" a schema... also jackk has a valid point what is pc.pk.idlaboratory!

Answer (score 2):

Try JPQL query:

```
String query= " SELECT pcKey, c.id, c.pcName 
    FROM Computer c RIGHT JOIN Pckey pcKey 
    WHERE pcKey.id IS NOT NULL AND pcKey.idLaboratory = :laboratoryId";
```